# Issues Populating MVC Html.DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to poulate a DropDownList with the contents of a Dictionary which is like this:

```
public static readonly IDictionary<string, string> VideoProviderDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                {"1", "Atlantic"},
                {"2", "Blue Ridge"},
                ...
```

For the model I have:

```
public string[] VideoProvider { get; set; }
            public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
```

In the controller, I am trying to populate the list:

```
 [HttpGet]
       public ActionResult Register()
       {
            var model = new RegisterViewModel();
            model.Items = new SelectList(VideoProviders.VideoProviderDictionary);

           return View(model);
       }
```

The issue is in the markup, there is no overload for DropDownList that takes a lambda expression:

```
 @Html.DropDownList(Model -> model.Items)
```

I tried to use:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Items)
```

But I get the error:

```
CS1501: No overload for method 'DropDownListFor' takes 1 arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Register()
   {
        var model = new RegisterViewModel();
        Viewbag.Items = new SelectList(VideoProviders.VideoProviderDictionary);
        ......
        ......
        return View(model);
   }
```

View :

```
@Html.DropDownList("VideoProvider",Viewbag.Items as SelectList)
```

OR For strongly typed dropdownlist do this :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.VideoProvider,Viewbag.Items as SelectList)
```

Model:

```
public string VideoProvider { get; set; }   //Correct here
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }  //if you are using Viewbag to bind dropdownlist(which is a easiest and effective way in MVC) then you don't need any model property for dropdown,you can remove this property.
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'DropDownListFor' takes 1 arguments

Comment: Befoe I mark your anser correct, it's displaying each item in the list as [1 - Comcast], etc. How do I modify my controller code to just make it Comcast or whatever the value is in the dictionary?

Comment: I got it. I just set it Value. Thanks

Comment: @user2471435 I don't understand this answer. So, you want to return the value in the "Items" property?

Comment: @user2471435..sorry for late reply i have a bad internet connection today.. just see updated answer and correct small issues in model and dropdownlist...model property VideoProvider will have selected dropdown value on post controller.. thanks..

Answer (score 2):

In your case -

Model:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{

    public static readonly IDictionary<string, string> VideoProviderDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {{"1", "Atlantic"},
            {"2", "Blue Ridge"}};

    public string VideoProvider { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register() {
        var model = new RegisterViewModel();
        model.Items = new SelectList(RegisterViewModel.VideoProviderDictionary, "key", "value");
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VideoProvider, Model.Items)
```